# Change asp.net components css class if browser is IE

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview one of it's columns ItemStyle has a css class named xyz i want to change css class to xyzie if the browser is IE , how can i do that ?

example code :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="y" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AllowSorting="True" CellSpacing="5" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="x" HeaderText="x" SortExpression="x" >
    <ItemStyle CssClass="xyz" /> // want to change this to xyzie if the browser is ie
    </asp:BoundField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it server-side then you can use [HttpBrowserCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities(VS.90).aspx) object.

[HOWTO article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311281).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IE specific [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

This will allow you to add IE specific classes:

```
<!--[if IE ]>  
  <body class="ie">  
<![endif]-->  
<!--[if !IE]>-->  
  <body>  
<!--<![endif]-->
```

In your CSS you would have an `ie` class with specific overriding behavior.

Comment: @Oded i've tried that already but it doesn't work between <asp:xxx></asp:xxx> tags.

Comment: @Oded: You've mentioned (right) in the beginning that conditional comments are IE-specific. By using your example code non-IE users will end up getting two BODY tags.

Comment: @dnn - If you post your code, it helps people understand the exact issue. In the future, always post the relevant code. Please edit your question and add your code. The answer from @volpav is probably what you need.

Comment: @volpav - I suggest you _reread_ the example. Non IE browsers will only get the second `body` tag, as the first one is commented out.

Comment: @Oded: Sorry, didn't see that the first BODY tag is actually a part of the HTML comment.

Comment: @volpav - No problem, it isn't that easy to spot :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you figure out the type of browser, you can dyanmically change CSS. My answer for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615944/loading-css-dynamically-in-asp-net) might be of some help